# Expiry date of custard powder?

Tags: custard

I bought a pack of 'Custard Power' around 4 year ago. I placed the pack in my store room and completely forgot about it until now. The packet was 100% unopened until yesterday, when I found it. I cannot seem to find an expiry date, but the powder still seems fine.

Can I use it, or should I throw it and get fresh?

Comment: Without an ingredients list and a lot more information we can't answer this.  After 4 years I'd just throw it out.

Comment: IF it is the kind of custard powder common around here, it is a case of "see: cornstarch" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Products like custard powder don't come with a use by date, instead they have "best before".

To be honest I see no reason why if kept dry custard powder would ever be inedible. Especially if it is just the corn flour and colour mix.

Answer (score 1):

Well last week on 30/12/2017 I made up some custard powder to have with some ripe bananas. It was lovely, just like school pudding from many, many years ago.
The lid showed best before December 1995 - absolutely fine for 22 years old :)
Yes, 22 years old. The powder hadn't gone a funny colour nor had it gone lumpy. It was just like new power really.